# Excel mover valores não duplicados entre duas colunas para uma terceira

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou com uma dúvida e não consigo uma resposta plausível.
Tenho uma planilha na qual eu gostaria de fazer uma comparação entre duas colunas e dizer para a mesma que se houver um valor que não seja duplicado, que esse mesmo valor seja movido para uma nova coluna. Por exemplo:

Tenho a Coluna "**A**" e "**B**", nessas colunas existe um sequência de números de 6 dígitos, por exemplo:

```
   A       B

519294  519522
519364  519499
519365  519501
519366  519500
519381  519494
519382  519492
519389  519493
519422  519491
519428  519483
```

Eu quero fazer uma comparação da coluna "A" utilizando a coluna "B", se o valor da coluna "A" não for encontrado na coluna "B" esse mesmo valor deve ser movido para uma nova coluna "C" por exemplo.

Se possível gostaria de usar uma formula ou um VBA que fizesse essa consulta e caso fosse um valor falso onde o referido valor não fosse encontrado na coluna "B" ele pudesse ser movido.

Fico muito grato se alguém puder me ajudar com um VBA ou Formula mesmo.

Comment: alguma coisa como em C4 pôr  `=IF(A4==B4; ; A4)`?

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer fazer. Você quer mover o valor da coluna A para C apenas se ele existir em B? A célula em A deve ficar vazia ou manter o valor? E as células de C que não receberem um valor? Além disso, seu exemplo não é bom, todos números são diferentes, não tem nenhuma match. Seria melhor você mudar seu exemplo e apresentar também o resultado esperado com a fórmula ou com VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será que um PROCV combinado com SE e SEERRO não te resolve?

```
=SE(SEERRO(PROCV(A1;B:B;1;FALSO);0)=0;A1;"")
```

Explicação: se o PROCV retornar um erro, indicando que o valor em A não foi encontrado em B, a fórmula retornara o valor de A. Se o valor em A for encontrado em B, a fórmula retornará vazia ("").

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi seu problema, o código abaixo faz o que você precisa. Faça as adaptações necessárias caso use colunas além da "Z" ou pegue automaticamente o número da última linha da coluna, por exemplo.

Dica: coloque um valor na coluna "A" que exista na coluna "B" para se certificar que o código funciona.

```
Dim i, j, LinhaInicial, LinhaFinal, ColunaResultado   As Integer

Dim ColunaBase, ColunaComparacao As String

LinhaInicial = 1
LinhaFinal = 9
ColunaBase = "A"
ColunaComparacao = "B"
ColunaResultado = 3 'Corresponde a coluna "C"


For j = LinhaInicial To LinhaFinal

 For i = LinhaInicial To LinhaFinal

  If Range(ColunaBase & j).Value = Range(ColunaComparacao & i).Value Then

   'Encontrou o mesmo valor, deve comparar o próximo valor
   GoTo AchouMesmoValor

  End If

 Next i

 'Se chegou aqui é por que não encontrou o mesmo valor
 'Coloca o valor em uma nova coluna
 'Calcula o código ASCII para a coluna (67 = "C")
 Range(Chr(64 + ColunaResultado) &     LinhaInicial).Value = Range(ColunaBase & j).Value

 'Prepara para próxima coluna a copiar valor encontrado
 ColunaResultado = ColunaResultado + 1

AchouMesmoValor:

Next j
```